# `Fermat-Theorem and Linear equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

This question is related to number theory and i am getting stuck on it it is
: 2^98 when divided by 33 what is the remainder?

i am pretty sure you solve it using fermat theorem I think , you first take mod 3 and mod 11 and , make a linear equation (this is where i am getting stuck )

Comment: $2^5\equiv -1\implies 2^{95}\equiv -1\implies 2^{98}\equiv -8\equiv 25$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By Euler's totient theorem we know that as 2 and 33 are coprime so:-
$$2^{\varphi(33)} \equiv 1(\text{mod }33)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2^{20} \equiv 1(\text{mod }33)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2^{80} \equiv 1(\text{mod }33)$$
Thus:-
$$2^{80}\cdot2^{18} \equiv 1\cdot(2^{5})^{3}\cdot2^{3} \equiv (32)^{3}\cdot8 \equiv (-1)^{3}\cdot8 \equiv -8 \equiv 25(\text{mod }33) $$